# trying to automate flipkart website using cypress. after landing on the home page>click on mobiles>scroll down to Apple Smartphones and click View All

Tags: cypress

So when ever I'm trying to access the element `#container ._1AtVbE` but in DOM it giving me 30 results which include Apple smart phones.  But in the cypress runner it's giving 13 and the page is not loading. Once i physically scroll to the results bottom page then the remaining items are generating.

Here's my code that i tried:

```
/// <reference types ="cypress"/>

describe('All login test', () =>{

    beforeEach( () =>{
        cy.visit('https://www.flipkart.com/')
    
    })

    it.only("simi", () => {

        cy.get('._1ch8e_').contains('Mobiles').click()
       cy.get('#container [class="_1AtVbE col-12-12').contains('Apple SmartPhones').find('div.Nyt1vx').scrollIntoView().find('._1xCO19')  
       
       ///cy.get('#container ._1AtVbE',{timeout:50000}).should('be.visible')
           
      

    })

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Once i physically scroll to the results bottom page...***

Cypress has the command `scrollTo('bottom')` which does exactly that.
Ref: [documentation scrollto](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/scrollTo#Position)

The question is where to add the scroll (must be a list or other scrollable element).

I can't tell from your code, because those are the **worst** selectors.

Assuming it's `#container`...

```js
cy.get('#container').scrollTo('bottom')  // scroll to bottom of container
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very quick work-around this, at least based on my limited knowledge in Python.

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--force-device-scale-factor=0.1")
```

It will zoom out to 0.1 and load everything in one go.